# how to use multiple controls with extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4

just been thru the following example.

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/guide/application_architecture

This walks thru setting a clean mvc structure and adding a grid to a page. On my website i wish to use many extjs features. But would like some clarity on the following.

1) typically would 1 website have only one app.js or would i create a new application per feature. So if i would like 1) contact info grid 2) news grid 3) a chart. Does mean 3 applications.

This is how i currently load my application ( which is a grid )

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Account Manager</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

app.js

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'AM',
    appFolder: 'app',
    controllers: [
            'Users'
            ],
    launch: function () {
        Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'userlist',
                    title: 'Users',
                    html: 'List of users will go here'
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: did you ever resolve this. I too am working on implementing a web application that has multiple pages with a different component or multiple components on a single page. I have had issues trying to get them to render correctly with a model theme for one component interfering with another. In the end I have just written on file for each component which is making this project huge. Could you comment on what you resolved to do doing.

Answer (score 1):

@Frosty, You only need one application file per website.

You are encouraged to create separate classes for grids, charts and any other components that you will be using in your website. Each class should go into a separate file.

So then when you create an instance of your component using Ext.create, EXTJS4 will dynamically load that javascript file. This helps with performance issues in a large application as all the files don't need to be brought down on the page load.

Comment: in the above example the launch method creates the viewport. Obviously i don't want this grid on every page. So do i move the launch to separate js file?

Comment: From my understanding the Ext.Application class is primarily used for single-page apps. That is the user browses to a page (index.html) and stays on the page for the duration of their time spent on your site. All content and components are then brought in dynamically using ExtJS. More information is available in the docs at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.app.Application

Comment: To summarise, if the user is staying on the same page then you only need 1 Ext.Application file. If the user will be browsing to multiple pages then it might be best to look at implementing ExtJS4 differently on your site i.e. without using Ext.Application

Personally I have never built an application or website using this single-page architecture as I find it too restrictive for a large scale app.